# Parsing and data presentation in Django

Tags: python, xml, django, xpath

For some time now, I've been using a pattern which I think could be done more elegantly. 
I have a lot of XML files that need to be represented in a Django views. My current approach is like this:

I get a XML response from an API which gives me several documents.

First I define a mock class like this:

```
class MockDocument:
    pass
```

Then I write an XPath expression that gives me a list of the document nodes:

```
from lxml import etree   
with open("xmlapiresponse.xml", "r") as doc:
    xml_response = doc.read()   
tree = etree.fromstring(xml_response)                                                        
document_nodes = tree.xpath("//documents/item")
```

Now I iterate over the different documents and their fields using nested `for`-loops:

```
# list for storing the objects
document_objects = []
for document in document_nodes:
    # create a MockDocument for each item returned by the API
    document_object = MockDocument()    
    for field in document:
        # store the corresponding fields as object attributes
        if field.tag == "something":
            document.something = field.text
    document_objects.append(document)
```

Now I can pass the list of mock objects to a Django view and represent them in the template in whichever way I want. Could this be done in a simpler fashion, though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a generator function gives you some flexibility.  You don't have to create a list.

```
def generate_documents( document_nodes ):

    for document in document_nodes:
        # create a MockDocument for each item returned by the API
        document_object = MockDocument()    
        for field in document:
            # store the corresponding fields as object attributes
            if field.tag == "something":
                document.something = field.text
        yield  document_object
```

You can do this of the list object is somehow important.

```
document_objects = list( generate_documents( document_nodes ) )
```

Or, more usefully, this

```
for d in generate_documents( document_nodes ):
    ... process the document ...
```

Which never actually creates a list object.